# Detach iframe with its current data from a parent to its own window

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to detach an iframe to its own window, leaving the **content intact and scripts running**?

It should be initiated from the parent window, but doing it from the iframe itself would not mind.

> It really doesn't matter how it is done, but the transition should be seamless, scripts running, unfinished inputs not lost.

As I am unskilled regarding this topic I can imagine it being either:

- CUT the iframe from the parent and put it in new window AS IS
- Transfer iframe's content into a new window.

Comment: no way to create an iframe without it having to load fresh. You can pass the data to it though either from server or local source. Question is far too broad for much more help than that

Comment: @charlietfl It's rather simple. User opens a chat which runs in an iframe. User decides he wants to popup the chat from current window/panel, stay in the chat and possibly even close the parent window.

Comment: So what is your specific problem then? New window = new iframe.

Comment: @charlietfl The problem is that I want to avoid reloads, because the chat is complicated and I am not sure (yet) how to reauthenticate the user seamlessly, possibly open their rooms and the stuff they had written and didn't send.. In other words - CUT the iframe AS IS and PUT it into stand-alone window (or the iframe's content.., whatever works.)

Comment: Can pass data to a  new window, can store data on users sessionStorage or localStorage, can communicate between a window you open and existing window but you will have to load a new frame

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, thanks. Put that as an answer and I will accept it.